# List inside the object remembers it's members after creating a new one

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

In root class I'm creating new object every time F3 keys is being pressed:
`class Browser(QtGui.QMainWindow):

indexlist = None

some code

def keyPressEvent(self, keyEvent):

 if keyEvent.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F3:

  keyEvent.accept()

  self.indexlist = self.ui.treeView.selectedIndexes()

  compareWin = CompareBox(self.indexlist, self)

  if compareWin.error == 1:

   self.indexlist = None

  else:

   self.indexlist = None

   compareWin.setModal(True)

   compareWin.show()`

And I have a class:
`class CompareBox(QtGui.QDialog):

 parameterlist = []

 def __init__(self, indexlist=None, parent=None):

   some code now then

   self.parameterlist.append(someobject) 

   again some code 

   self.parameterlist = [] 

   self.close()`


While my application works I'm creating these objects repeatedly and each time when new object is created it remembers parameterlist members from the previous one.
I've tried: del(parameterlist) but it didn't help.
Also I've noticed that destructors for these objects are called only when application is being closed. But my friend told me that it's Qt feature for checking how dialog window ended. I must admit that I'm quite puzzled and have completely no idea what's going on.

Comment: You are using class variables instead of instance variables.  Do not initialise `paramrterlist` in the class body, but rather in the constructor using `self.parameterlist = []`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew that my mistake must be simple, but I didn't think of that. Great thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the parameterlist you have delcared in the class is the same for each instance you create.

You should try something like this :

```
class CompareBox(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, indexlist=None, parent=None):
        some code now then
        self.parameterlist = []
        self.parameterlist.append(someobject) 
        again some code 
        self.close()
```